# Facebook Javascript SDK extended permissions not being asked/logout button not displaying

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I just began using the Facebook JavaScript SDK to allow users to log in to my website with Facebook.

The code containing the scope and data-auto-logout-link:

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,user_birthday,user_location" onlogin="checkLoginState();" data-auto-logout-link="true" >
</fb:login-button>
```

There are two issues I am currently experiencing:

1:  Only the standard permissions (public_profile, email) are being asked when the connection prompt pops up for all but one Facebook account.  The only account that the extended permissions are working on is the account that the app is registered under.  All other accounts only receive a pop-up requesting the standard permissions and not the extended permissions...

2:  Additionally, the data-auto-logout-link only displays for the one account which the app is registered under.  All other accounts tried do not display the Log Out link... I have tried 6 separate Facebook accounts all of which behave in the exact same way.

I am able to "Log In" with Facebook and retrieve the basic information for all the accounts that I have tried... but as stated above, extended permissions are not not being requested and Log Out button is not displayed for 5/6 accounts.

I would like to provide a link to the site, however it is being developed locally....

I also would have liked to provide screenshots detailing the problem... but I do not yet have sufficient stack overflow reputation

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I suspect that the two issues are tied together...

If any additional code is required, just ask and I would be happy to provide it.  However everything seems to be working with the exceptions of the above mentioned issues...

Thanks in Advance for your time and energy,

Alex Gomes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please note that-

> From [**v2.0**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) onwards, the permissions other than `public_profile`, `email` and the `user_friends` need to the submitted for review before you can make your app **live**; until then, only the testers/admin/developers of the app will be able to test app with those permissions.

So, if you wish to test your app with other users, add developers/testers/admins to your app and they can test your app successfully.

[image]

After your app is completed-

1. Go to *Status & Review* and submit your app for [login review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login).
2. Switch your app to **live** from the development mode and its done.

   [image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Much appreciated!  That sounds like it is definitely the answer!

Comment: Confirmed!  Got to work and added some developers to the app... and voila!  Thanks again!